# Shifted eigenvalues and Gershgorin theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

Suppose we have a $n\times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $\mathbf{A}$.
Based on Gershgorin circles theorem all the eigenvalues of the, $\mathbf{A}=[a_{ij}]$, are located in the union of $n$ circles: 
\begin{equation*}
  \bigcup_{i=1}^{p}\bigg\{r\in \mathbb{R}:|r-a_{ii}|\leq R_{i}(\mathbf{A})\bigg\}
\end{equation*}
where $R_{i}(\mathbf{A})=\sum_{j,j\neq i}^{n}|a_{ij}|$. Therefore, bounds of Gershgorin:
\begin{equation*}
[\lambda^{\geq}(\mathbf{A}) = min_{i} (a_{ii}-R_{i}(\mathbf{A})), \lambda^{\leq}(\mathbf{A}) = max_{i} (a_{ii}+R_{i}(\mathbf{A}))]
\end{equation*}
Now, we create a family of matrices:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{A}(t) = t\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{D},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{D}$ is the same as $\mathbf{A}$ with all the off-diagonal entries reduced to zero and $\mathbf{B}$ is the same as $\mathbf{A}$ with all the diagonal entries reduced to zero all
along the interval $0<t\leq1$.

Are the following statements correct?
\begin{equation}
λ_1(A(t))>λ_1(A) 
\\
λ_n(A(t))<λ_n(A)
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_{1}(\mathbf{A}(t))$ and $\lambda_{n}(\mathbf{A}(t))$ are the smallest and largest eigenvalue repectively.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $s_{ii}$??? And how is $\lambda^\ge$ defined? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I correct that. it is $a_{ii}$
I define $\lambda^{\geq}$ and $\lambda^{\leq}$. Lower and Upper bounds respectively.

Comment: These relations are of course correct. Just by the definition of $R_i$ and $\lambda^\ge$.

Comment: Do you have any idea to prove?

Comment: There is not much to prove. Everything follows from $R_i(A(t))\le R_i(A)$.

Comment: What? It's trivial. $R_i(A(t)) = \sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}(t)| = t\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}| = tR_i(A)\le R_i(A)$.

Comment: How about this? $\lambda_{1}(\mathbf{A}(t))>\lambda_{1}(\mathbf{A})$
and $\lambda_{p}(\mathbf{A}(t))<\lambda_{p}(\mathbf{A})$

Comment: You cannot make a statement about these relations, in general.

Comment: Thanks. This was the main question......

Comment: If this was the main question, then why didn't you ask it in the question???

Comment: Ok. I edit that.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98054/discussion-between-watsonabb-and-amsmath).

Comment: @watsonabb What have you done so far? would you show your effort to answer your own questions?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. E.g. equalities hold when $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

However, the statements are true in almost all generic cases. By relabelling the rows and columns of $A$ if necessary, we may assume without loss of generality that $d_{11}\le d_{22}\le\cdots\le d_{nn}$.

Suppose that the first column of $A$ contains a nonzero off-diagonal entry. Let $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Then
$$
\lambda_\min(A)=\min_{\|u\|_2=1}u^TAu\le e_1^TAe_1=a_{11}=d_{11}=\lambda_\min(D).
$$
Since the first column of $A$ contains a nonzero off-diagonal entry, $e_1$ is not an eigenvector of $A$. The inequality above must therefore be strict. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_\min(A)
&=t\lambda_\min(A)+(1-t)\lambda_\min(A)\\
&<t\lambda_\min(A)+(1-t)\lambda_\min(D)\\
&=\lambda_\min(tA)+\lambda_\min((1-t)D)\\
&\le\lambda_\min(tA+(1-t)D)\\
&=\lambda_\min(D+tB).
\end{aligned}
Similarly, if there is a nonzero off-diagonal entry on the last column of $A$, then $\lambda_\max(A)>\lambda_\max(D+tB)$.